# Arguments built from array not working without eval

Tags: bash

I have a little rsync script:

```
OPTS="--some --long --opts"
ORIGIN="/folder/xy/"
DESTINATION="/backups/xy/"
EXCLUDES=( "/dir1" "/dir2" "/dir3" )

PREFIXED_EXCLUDES=( ${EXCLUDES[@]/#/"--exclude=\""} ) #prepend <--exclude=">
ESCAPED_EXCLUDES=( ${PREFIXED_EXCLUDES[@]/%/"\""} ) #append <">

(1) echo rsync $OPTS ${ESCAPED_EXCLUDES[@]} $ORIGIN $DESTINATION
(2) rsync $OPTS ${ESCAPED_EXCLUDES[@]} $ORIGIN $DESTINATION
(3) eval rsync $OPTS ${ESCAPED_EXCLUDES[@]} $ORIGIN $DESTINATION
```

(1) will echo exactly the command as I want it to be

(2) ignores the --exclude arguments, but only them, other arguments work

(3) works properly

Why does it not work without `eval`? I tried to come up with a simpler example, but none came to mind.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to add quotes to the `--exclude` arguments? If you were to quote the expansions in the `rsync` invocation -- `rsync "$OPTS" "${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=}" "$ORIGIN" "$DESTINATION"` -- it should all work just fine.

Comment: @rici - Good point, but you probably don't want to double-quote `$OPTS`.

Comment: @mklement0: True. It would have been better to use `OPTS=(--some --long --opts)` and `"${OPTS[@]}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this will work:

```
EXCLUDE_DIRS=( "/dir1" "/dir2" "/dir3" )
EXCLUDES=()
for dir in "${EXCLUDE_DIRS[@]}"; do
    EXCLUDES+=( "--exclude=$dir" )
done

rsync $OPTS "${EXCLUDES[@]}" "$ORIGIN" "$DESTINATION"
```

All quoting (or lack thereof) above is very deliberate.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work! Even without the quotes in the last line actually. So problem solved, but nothing learned. Could you explain why your solution works and my does not? I suspect it must be something about the away I build the "--exclude=" around the directories

Comment: You are adding literal double quotes to the excluded filenames, and rsync cannot find a file named literally `"/dir1"` (with the quotes). When you `eval` it, then the shell gets another chance to interpret the quotes before actually invoking rsync

Comment: Note also that `${array[@]}` behaves differently from `"${array[@]}"` when the elements  contain whitespace. It's always safer to quote all your variables (except when you specifically want to subject their values to word splitting and filename pattern expansion, which is the case with $OPTS here).

Comment: @user3200072: Another way to put it: Double-quoting an array reference on a command line correctly translates each array element - even if it contains whitespace - to a distinct command-line argument (thus, you needn't and indeed mustn't add literal double quotes to the array elements).

Comment: if I manually enter `--exclude="/dir1"` on the commandline it works as it should. Your example also works if I change the line to `EXCLUDES+=( --exclude="$dir" )`

But you're right, it has to have something to do with those quotes, when I change my original code to
`PREFIXED_EXCLUDES=( ${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=} ) #prepend <--exclude=>`
`ESCAPED_EXCLUDES=( ${PREFIXED_EXCLUDES[@]/%/} ) #do nothing`

it works.

Comment: @user3200072 `--exclude="$dir"` is effectively the same as `"--exclude=$dir"`: the shell turns either into a single string with quotes removed before assigning it to the array element (note that the former case only results in a single string because `--exclude=` is directly attached to `"$dir"` and contains no whitespace). By contrast, your original approach explicitly added double quotes to the string value itself.

Comment: @user3200072, If you do this on the command line, it won't work: `--exclude="\"/dir1\""` -- this is what your code is doing. When you eyeball it and type the number of quotes you *think* bash should be seeing, then you're implicitly doing an eval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eval` because quotes are not processed after expanding variables. Variable expansions undergo word splitting and filename globbing, no other special characters are processed; if the variable is expanded inside double quotes, even these do not take place.

You should actually write:

```
eval "rsync $OPTS ${ESCAPED_EXCLUDES[@]} $ORIGIN $DESTINATION"
```

to avoid an extra round of word splitting and globbing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get that. Without `eval` $OPTS, $DESTINATION and $ORIGIN and the rest is understood correctly by rsync, why not the array? As fas as I see, I don't need any processing of quotes, I just want to pass it verbatim to rsync as an argument

Comment: You need the quotes to be removed, which is part of quote processing. You have `--exclude="/dir1"`. Since the quotes aren't processed, this excludes a directory whose name contains those literal quotes.